# Server not reachable after setting static IP

Tags: networking, debian, vmware-workstation, static-ip

I am doing experiments with a Debian 10 VM on my PC.
Everything worked well until i tried to setup a static IP.

The static IP is working now, and i am able to ping and traceroute to e.g. google.com and use APT.

BUT, now i can't connect to the Debian-VM from outside. SSH and Apache are up and running, ports are opened and the services are listening on those ports. 
There are no errors inside the Log-files. iptables is set to accept everything (for now..)

My PC is running Windows 10 and I use VMware for Virtualisation.

The VM got it's own Virtual Network where ->

```
DHCP Disabled
DNS points to 1.1.1.1 , 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
Subnet Mask is set to 255.255.255.0
Subnet IP is set to 192.168.78.0
Gateway IP is set to 192.168.78.2
```

my /etc/network/interfaces file contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.78.129
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.78.2
dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

output of 'ip ro sh':

```
default via 192.168.78.2 dev ens33 onlink
192.168.78.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.78.129
```

Comment: How does it look when you enable dhcp? Show ouput of ip addr, ip ro sh, etc. And where are you connecting from? Show `iptables -L -n` on the VM and if applicable the gateway.

Comment: Nothing changed when enabling DHCP. ive just found out myself and added an answer to my question :P

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out myself..

Problem was solved by adding a broadcast-address to /etc/network/interfaces